# Event-Based Communications Between Microservices without a Shared Event Libary?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm learning about microservices.

On one hand, the literature recommends using asynchronous event-publishing for microservices that need to collaborate on sagas or take action on events published by other services.

On the other hand, the same literature recommends not using a shared library to define common events because that couples the microservices through that event library.

Am I taking crazy pills? Aren't those microservices coupled by those events anyway if they rely on them? If so, what is the advantage of coding the exact same events with the same definition in two (or even more) different places? Isn't that a total violation of the DRY principle?

I'm starting to smell a code smell that starts with the initials BS. Will someone help me drink the rest of this koolaid? Or did I just see the emperor with his clothes off for a second?

Answer (score 3):

> If so, what is the advantage of coding the exact same events with the same definition in two (or even more) different places?

There could be a number of advantages -- the microservices might be implemented using different languages.  Or using the same language, but different in memory representations of the data to suit there specific needs.  Or even the "same" in memory representations, but different *versions*, because they are on different deployment schedules.

There's nothing inherently wrong with sharing the labor of preparing a messaging library among the implementations of your services.  But that should be an opt-in, rather than being a requirement.  In particular, a team always has the option of replacing the library if the shared implementation is getting in the way.

Two services that agree that the messages are going to use UTF-8 encoded JSON documents should not be required to use the same *parser* -- the choice of parser is an implementation detail.  The coupling is to the schema (the agreement about the semantics of the bytes in the message), not to the implementation.

Comment: Using the same event library isn't just to save labor, but to promote correctness and eliminate errors, one of which you mentioned: mismatched protocol versions between the different microservices that are attempting to communicate. Sure, if it's a heterogenous system of .NET services and Java services, one single library can't define event structures for both. But the .NET services could all share one, and the Java services could as well, and that would be better, even if the libraries are just interfaces, deferring the implementation to the consumers. The docs disparaged this. I call BS.

Comment: It is nice to hear someone "keep it real" and say yes, the Event objects are being serialized as JSON. I wonder how many projects have been crushed under the weight of this ideology.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer the question. I agree that "There's nothing inherently wrong with sharing the labor of preparing a messaging library among the implementations of your services." I just don't agree that the best reason for doing so is only to save labor.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat events as plain data objects, you don't need a library to deal with them - other than generic messagning and serialization/deserialization code.

The whole point of microservices is to have independent development cycles, so as soon as you introduce the common library, you are starting to make a "distributed monolyth". Any change in this library will cause a redeployment of all microservices.

Without event-specific library the only dependency you introduce it a knowledge of particular event structure from another microservice. Well, this is a necessary evil.

Comment: Thanks for this. My rebuttal: YES there must be knowledge of particular events from other microservices and the event's contents. Given that, we can either formalize that knowledge by committing it to code, or keep it anecdotal; from what I know about the lossiness of speech and documentation, that's always going to be a error-prone.

My other point is, why not redeploy all the microservices at once? CI makes that easy.

Yes, the fiction that microservices exist in isolation can be helpful, but it can also be onerous. Experts know when the rules should be bent.